# JavaScript - Math.floor(Math.random()) - Reposition <img> element

Tags: javascript, html, random, styles

I am trying to develop a function that randomly repositions an  element on a web document.  My current JavaScript program does not randomly change the element.style.left and element.style.top values of the  element id = "image".  Thanks for your help!

```
<html> <body>

<img id="image" src="happy.jpg" style="position:absolute;left:0px; 
top:0px; width:50px; height:50px;" />

<button onclick="RandomPositions()"> Random Position </button>

<script>
 function RandomPositions() {
    var Hero = document.getElementById("image");
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    var HeroX = Hero.style.left;
    HeroX = x + 'px';
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    var HeroY = Hero.style.top; 
    HeroY = y + 'px';
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use only the element itself, because you had as reference a primitive value (string), not the reference to style.

```js
 function RandomPositions() {
    var Hero = document.getElementById("image");
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    Hero.style.top = y + 'px';
    Hero.style.left = x + 'px';       
 }
```

```html
<img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/75/75/" style="position:absolute;left:0px; 
top:0px; width:50px; height:50px;" />
<button onclick="RandomPositions()"> Random Position </button>
```

Comment: It Works :-) Thank you, NINA!

Answer (score 1):

Remove HeroX and HeroY variables. When changing these varibles, image style not change.

```
function RandomPositions() {
    var Hero = document.getElementById("image");
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    Hero.style.left = x + 'px';
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    Hero.style.top = y + 'px';
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var Hero = document.getElementById("image");
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
Hero.style.left = x +'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

It works like this :

```
var Hero = document.getElementById("image");
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
Hero.style.left = x +'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the variables to the new the object.

Add this to you code.

```
Hero.style.left = HeroY;
Hero.style.left = HeroX;
```

Anyway the img is moving just on the Y axis.